# Why does MapView show grey tiles and not the map?

Tags: android, android-mapview, tiles, sha1, api-key

Ok, so I got my SHA1 fingerprint by creating a batch file. After that, I went to the "Services" page and enabled Google Maps API v2 and v3. I also went to the "API Access" page and created a new Android Key with the SHA1;PACKAGENAME. After this, I went to my project folder and added the following code:

```
<permission
    android:name            = "com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel = "signature" 
/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion     = "0x00020000"
    android:required        = "true" 
/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<meta-data
        android:name    = "com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value   = "APIKEY" 
/>
```

I also created an XML file and pasted the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    xmlns:android           = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id              = "@+id/mapview_MV"
    android:layout_width    = "fill_parent"
    android:layout_height   = "fill_parent"
    android:clickable       = "true"
    android:apiKey          = "APIKEY"
/>
```

After compiling and running the project on my HTC One X+, I saw nothing more than bunch of grey tiles. I also tried to use a MapView in code as shown below:

```
/********************************************************************
* ONCREATE                                                          *
********************************************************************/
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView( R.layout.general_layout );

    MapView mapView = new MapView( GamePage.this, "APIKEY" );
    MapController mc = mapView.getController();
    String coordinates[] = {"1.352566007", "103.78921587"};
    double lat = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[0]);
    double lng = Double.parseDouble(coordinates[1]);

    GeoPoint p = new GeoPoint( (int) (lat * 1E6), (int) (lng * 1E6) );

    mc.animateTo(p);
    mc.setZoom(17); 

    FrameLayout fl = ( FrameLayout ) findViewById(R.id.general_frameHolder_FL);
    fl.addView(mapView);
}
```

I get to see the following error:

```
Couldn't get connection factory client
```

Can anyone tell me what the hell I'm doing wrong!?

Comment: which keystore did you use to create your SHA1 key?

Comment: debug.keystore in C:\Users\%Username%\.android\

Comment: well, it says that you have to submit MD5 fingerprint, not SHA1    
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey

Comment: Nope, it doesn't accept MD5 anymore. read the comment in the page when creating an Android Key. Also, you're looking to Google Maps Android v1 API Key and it will be decapitated soon. You need to look to Google Maps Android v2 API Key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution for the problem. What I needed to do was delete the Google Play Services in the SDK Manager and reinstall it, because I missed lots of packages for some reason. Thanks to Fido, I found out that MapView isn't supported in Google Maps Android v2 API and read the whole introduction at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#specifying_permissions.

After that, I also found a site where you can solve the NoClassFoundError at:
http://www.user.tu-berlin.de/hennroja/tutorial_fixing_java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError%20com.google.android.gms.R$styleable.html

It took me +- 5 hours to solve this freaking issue with the new Google Maps API.

Comment: Map API v2 have the new MapView: com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView, not com.google.android.maps.MapView

Answer (score 5):

When we are implement `MapView` in `Fragment` or `Activity` must implement its life cycle methods [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView#public-methods)

put **mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);**

inside `onCreateView()` or `onCreate()`

```
 @Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mMapView.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try enable Google maps Android API v2 
[image]

Meta key must below Application Tag

```
<permission
    android:name            = "com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel = "signature" 
/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion     = "0x00020000"
    android:required        = "true" 
/>

<uses-permission android:name="com.example.test.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

    <!-- key v2 -->
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="Bla Bla" />

    <uses-library
        android:name="com.google.android.maps"
        android:required="false" />
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/st_google_activity_main" >
    </activity>
</application>
```

And if you use MapView, You must forward all the [Activity life cycle methods](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwz2b.png).

XML layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />
</LinearLayout>
```

class

```
public class MainActivity extends android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity implements OnMapClickListener , OnMapLongClickListener , OnCameraChangeListener {
    private GoogleMap                   mMap;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_googlev2);
        mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Xarialon I've update my answer. check for it. Have you ever tested with SupportMapFragment?

Comment: Yes, I tried to use the other life cycles too, but it doesn't support mapView.onResume, mapView.onPause and mapView.onDestroy. Still no changes here...

Comment: @Xarialon you are using MapView of google map V1 (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/v1/mapkey) for google map V2. Try SupportMapFragment, i've update my post

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me api-key issue ..
Try to give in this way

```
android:apiKey="0BYX7MFyg8lWRKFxzwG-D93VMxZP6wH5eObwEtw"
```

Check you logs ..are you getting any error log from Google Map Lib ?

Comment: I get to see this error:
Couldn't get connection factory client.

Btw, I also tried to generate a new key, but still no changes here!

Comment: You can check few things...  1) Internet connection 2)       mapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true); then check with zoom in and zoom out...even You can try with new lat , longs ( which should be actual of some place )